# Zebra Android SDK printer not printing images with android 11: bluetooth light is flashing but not printing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, zebra-printers

We have an android app in order to print images using the android sdk for zebra (ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar). The printer is the ZQ320 model and is in ZPL_HYBRID mode.
The same app with the same printer in some devices doesn't work: the bluetooth light flashing but it stopping flashing and ending up not printing anything meanwhile in other devices prints okey.
We are trying finding out if any exception is thrown but it seems no exception throws in all code as far as we know.

```
 public static void printBitmapZebra(ZebraPrinter printer, Bitmap path) throws ConnectionException {

        String setSizeCommand = "^XA^LL" + path.getHeight() + "^XZ";
        
        printer.sendCommand(setSizeCommand);

        ZebraImageAndroid oZebraImage = new ZebraImageAndroid(path);

        printer.printImage(
                oZebraImage, 0, 0,
                path.getWidth(),
                path.getHeight(), false);
    }
```

And this code is invoked from this:

```
public void onClickPrint(View view) {
    new Thread(() -> {

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            String mac = macAddress.getText().toString();
            if (isNullOrEmpty(mac)) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> UIHelper.showCustomToast(
                        this,
                        "Debe de especificar una dirección para la impresora."));
                return;
            }

            showModalLoadingDialog("Impresión", "Generando imagen");

            Bitmap bm = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromWebview(oWebViewBmpGenerator);
            BitmapUtils.saveBitmapToTempFolder(this,bm);
            bm = BitmapUtils.toGrayScale(bm);
            bm = BitmapUtils.getScaledPrinterBitmap(bm, 203); // 203 -> ZEBRA ZQ320

            if (bm == null) {
                throw new Exception("No se generó una imagen para imprimir.");
            }

            updateLoadingDialog( "Conectando con la impresora");
            SettingsHelper.saveBluetoothAddress(PrintZebraActivity.this, mac);

            connection = new BluetoothConnection(macAddress.getText().toString());
            connection.open();
            ZebraPrintUtils.setStatus(connection);
            ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);

            updateLoadingDialog("Enviando imagen");
            ZebraPrintUtils.printBitmapZebra(printer, bm);
            connection.close();
            connection = null;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            cclsLog.log(this, e);
            UIHelper.showWarning(this, e);

        } finally {
            dismissModalProgressDialog();

            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Does anyone here have any ideas of how to tackle the problem?
Thank you in advance.

PD: Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the printer(ZQ320) firmware to latest version V81.20.22Z.zpl (https://www.zebra.com/es/es/support-downloads/printers/mobile/zq320.html#pageandfilelist_ac9a) the problem was fixed.